# ModuleNotFoundError using items.py

Tags: python-3.x, scrapy, scrapy-item

Trying to implement an Item Loader.

my class name in items.py:

```
SiemensLinkcontentItem
```

my import statements inside my spider:

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.loader import ItemLoader
from siemens_linkcontent.siemens_linkcontent.items import SiemensLinkcontentItem
```

I get the following error:

```
No module named 'siemens_linkcontent.siemens_linkcontent'
```

My path diagramm is the following:
[image]

Comment: Seems to be a problem with vs code. Using just ````from siemens_linkcontent.items import SiemensLinkcontentItem```` works but an error is still being displayed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use This One

```
- from siemens_linkcontent.items import SiemensLinkcontentItem
```

Comment: please write what you are trying to achieve with this piece of code. code only answers are discouraged in SO

Comment: Thank you. It works like this. VS Code is still showing an error though but that is acceptable